# Deserializing JSON string with JavaScriptSerializer to return a single dynamic object instead of an array of keys and values

Tags: c#, json, javascriptserializer

Consider the following JSON string in C#:

```
{
    "BuyerRegion":"BuyerRegion [0][27]",
    "SellerRegion":"SellerRegion [0][29]",
    "HubRegion":"HubRegion [0][31]",
    "PartNo":"TINT_MNUM [0][3]",
    "BuyerCompID":"BuyerCompId [0][28]",
    "SellerCompId":"SellerCompId [0][30]",
    "HubCompId":"HubCompId [0][32]"
}
```

I then tried to Deserialize the string into a dynamic object in C# using:

```
object obj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<object>(s); //where s contains the JSON string
```

However, the returning `obj` is an array of key/value pairs:

[image]

Any idea how I can have them deserialized into one single dynamic object where I can access the properties using:

```
obj.BuyerRegion //returns "BuyerRegion [0][27]"
```

JsonConvert/NewtonSoft isn't a choice.

Comment: You could deserialize to a `Dictionary<string, object>`, then convert to an `ExpandoObject` as shown in [IDictionary<string, object> to ExpandoObject extension method](https://theburningmonk.com/2011/05/idictionarystring-object-to-expandoobject-extension-method/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying several methods, I came to realize that accessing the properties is as easy as calling:

```
obj["BuyerRegion"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use instead of `object` some `ModelDto` and cast to it, I mean:

```
public class ModelDto {
  public string Key {get;set;}
  public string Value {get;set;}
}
```

Or you can use follwoing code to take value from dictionary by key:

```
string buyerRegion = dict["BuyerRegion"];
```

Or you can use ExpandoObject as suggested in a comments to your question.